# How to get new-style Windows drag&drop cursors

Tags: windows, winapi, drag-and-drop, mouse-cursor

How is it possible to use new-style dragging cursor on Windows when user is dragging something (e.g. image) from Explorer to my application?

[image: Windows drag&drop cursors]

In some apps (MS Paint, Visual Studio, Qt Creator, ...) old cursors are used, in others (Explorer, Skype, Chrome, Opera, ...) – new.

I’m talking only about the case when drag&drop operation was created **outside** of our application. So it is handled by other program (Explorer in my case).

Comment: the long way: Chrome is open source, just grep for drag and drop related functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the shell drag/drop helper object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997500.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. By the way Chromium implementation can be used as an example: [src/ui/base/dragdrop/drop_target.h](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/ui/base/dragdrop/drop_target.h)